# Getting human-readable value from Django's ChoiceField when nested in an ArrayField

Tags: python, django

To obtain the human readable value for a field with choices, Django provides the [`get_FOO_display()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) method.

How would one go about getting the human readable values when the field is inside an ArrayField?

eg: `foo_array = models.ArrayField(models.CharField(choices=choices))`

Answer (score 0):

Since the `ArrayField` doesn't have choices the model doesn't automatically get the method, but you can always implement it manually.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    foo_array = models.ArrayField(models.CharField(choices=choices))

    def get_foo_array_display(self):
        values = self.foo_array
        return [force_text(dict(self.foo_array.flatchoices).get(value, value), strings_only=True) 
                for value in values]
```